# Tangent Vectors to Fibers of the Hopf Map

Tags: tangent-spaces, hopf-fibration

So I'm viewing the Hopf map as a map from $\mathbb{C}^{2} \to \mathbb{R} \oplus \mathbb{C}$ by $(z,w) \to \left(\frac{1}{2}(|z|^{2}-|w|^{2}),z\bar{w}\right)$. I've concluded that the fiber including $(z,w) \in \mathbb{C}^{2}$ is the set of points $(e^{i\theta}z,e^{i\theta}w)$ for $0 \le \theta < 2\pi$. What I'm having trouble with is the following: I was told (in a text) that $i(z,w)$ is tangent to the fiber including $(z,w)$. As I understand it, this means $i(z,w)$ is a vector in the tangent space of each point in the fiber of $(z,w)$. Is this understanding correct, and if so how do I conclude that $i(z,w)$ is actually tangent to the fiber? Is there a fast way to check this with inner products (I'm viewing this problem from the category of Riemannian manifolds)?

Comment: **HINT**: What is $\frac{d}{d\theta} e^{i\theta}(z,w)$?

Comment: This derivative is just $i(e^{i\theta}z,e^{i\theta}w)$. So $i(e^{i\theta}z,e^{i\theta}w)$ is tangent to $(e^{i\theta}z,e^{i\theta}w)$. This is just another way of saying that $i(z,w)$ is tangent to the fiber because for $i(z,w)$ to be tangent to any element of the fiber, say $(e^{i\theta}z,e^{i\theta}w)$, we need that  $i(z,w)$ is a constant multiple of the derivative (with respect to $\theta$) of $(e^{i\theta}z,e^{i\theta}w)$ and that constant is precisely $e^{i\theta}$. Is this correct?